# Copying offset cells from a variable range

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I have a variable that is used as a range and am looking for a better way to copy/paste from it.  I know about the ".copy destination:=" method but I am copy/pasting the offset cells and not the variable range and I am have trouble figuring out how to do it without this ugly code:

```
current.Range(origin).Select
current.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)).Copy
current.Range(dest).Select
current.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
With current.Range(origin)
    current.Range(.Offset(0, 1), .Offset(0, 3)).Copy _ 
        Destination:=current.Range(dest).Offset(0, 1)
End With
```

or this one even better:

```
With current
    .Range(origin).Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 3).Copy _ 
        Destination:=.Range(dest).Offset(0, 1)
End With
```